# Is there a passport control at Hamburg Airport or at German airports?

Tags: germany, airports, schengen-visas, norway

I am a citizen of Norway, and I wonder if there is any passport control at the airport between Norway and Germany/Hamburg. 'cause I lost my passport in Germany, I have to apply for an emergency passport, which takes three weeks! But I want to solve this in Norway without informing the German police, and I must go home. I need to know that because I know that I will put myself in a difficult position at the slightest passport control.

Comment: I don't suppose you have one of the (relatively new) Norwegian national identity cards.  If you do, you can use that and you have no need whatsoever for a passport.  You'll also normally need a police report for the lost passport, so it will be difficult not to involve the German police without lying about where you lost it.

Comment: "without informing the German police" Why?

Comment: You should file a police report and at least inform your consulate immediately regardless, so that your passport may be included in the interpol database of lost and stolen documents, so that if anyone else got ahold of it, they cannot travel with it.

Comment: @jwenting let's try to assume the best and not accuse OP of committing a crime.

Comment: Find the next best customs office. Present them with any document identifying yourselves (anything with a picture on it).  They will provide you with an temporary passport on the spot.  Happend to my mom at crossinge the border to switzerland when her ID-card had expired ages ago.  Took 10 minutes time and a few Euros.

Comment: @markgraf "Customs" has nothing to do with this. Customs is about controlling the flow of goods (not people) across borders. Emergency travel documents have to be requested at embassies (more precisely: at consulates). The way of obtaining an emergency travel document is heavily dependent on your nationality and location.

Comment: The german "Zoll" does both and a lot more.

Comment: do you have another form of id?

Answer (score 20):

Norway and Germany are both in the Schengen Area, so there should be no systematic checks for immigration purposes. However:

- There can be random spot checks
- Both have announced the [temporary reintroduction of border controls](https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/policies/schengen-borders-and-visa/schengen-area/temporary-reintroduction-border-control_en)
- Airlines may ask for ID for security purposes, especially if you have checked bags (though policies for this, including what documents are accepted, vary between different countries and airlines)

It is probably safer to report your loss and apply for an emergency passport. I’m surprised an emergency passport could take 3 weeks, that would probable be for a regular one. They could possibly also provide some other form of temporary ID allowing you to return to Norway.

Comment: The announced temporary reintroduction of border controls does not affect this case, as the scope of the reintroduced border controls is the "land border with Austria" in the case of Germany, and the "ports with ferry connections to the Schengen area" in the case of Norway. However, IDs are routinely asked for at airports, so it would be risky to go without one.

Comment: I'd argue that Germany-Norway flights are frequent and cheap enough that it may very well be worth it to take the chance. *Worst* case they deny you checkin or boarding, at which point the ticket is lost.

Comment: @vidarlo I would personally recommend against that, getting detained during random spot checks seems like a potentially unfun time.

Comment: @ave In a western European country? I'd take the chance. It's not that many spot checks by police if you check in. On arrival in Norway is a possibility, but at that stage you're in your own country; a drivers license or bank id card will suffice.

Comment: Not really relevant to the answer, but regarding your last paragraph, the current wait time for a passport in Italy is 4-6 *months*, with emergency passports not too far behind, so anything is possible...

Comment: You (usually) don't need a full passport to return to your home country; most countries are able to issue you with a document that will let return on short notice. Here's the example for the UK: https://www.gov.uk/emergency-travel-document
I would be surprised if Norway didn't have a similar scheme, but for that you need to talk to the embassy.

Comment: In fact, here is the Norwegian equivalent: https://www.udi.no/en/want-to-apply/immigrants-passport-and-travel-document/travel-document-for-emergencies-laissez-passer/ 
I don't speak Norwegian, so I don't know how reliable this page is.

Comment: There *are* systematic checks.  You will not get to the gate without your documents being checked at a german airport.  Those controls are even fully automated at the Munich airport.  Presenting some form of identification is not only expected, it is *mandatory*

Comment: @markgraf for a flight to a Schengen destination? That would be surprising.

Comment: @markgraf To go to a Schengen destination you only need to present the boarding pass, not the identification, at least at the terminal 2 of the Munich airport (which I frequent regularly).

Comment: ID checks may be because the airline wants to prevent a secondary market in tickets - ie a different person travels from whose name is on the ticket. That's entirely up to the airline to enforce, but lack of ID could result in denied boarding.

Answer (score 8):

Your biggest risk here is that the airline will want to see your passport and deny boarding if you don't have one.

First of all you need to verify identity both for the airline at check in and for security. While the airline does not HAVE to check whether you have a valid passport, they sure CAN and they often do.

I found this to be very inconsistent: on some Schengen flights no one wanted to see any documents and on others they did check passports at check-in AND again at the gate when boarding. I don't think you can predict what exactly will happen.

Comment: ID checks on Schengen flights are actually very consistent, because most of the time they're purely a matter of airline policy (to prevent ticket resale). Some airlines (mostly low-cost) always do them,other airlines (mostly traditional) never do. Only very few carriers use checks only on selected routes.

Comment: @TooTea in some cases checks are made mandatory by national authorities, so even if an airline has a policy to not do it when they can they are forced to do so. There used to be some cases where it was mandatory only if you had checked luggage, not sure if that case still exists.

Comment: @TooTea my experience is different: I am almost never asked for ID when flying Germany -> Spain, and almost always asked for ID when flying Spain -> Germany, and of course that is a return flight with the same airline. Whether the obligation to check is imposed by the departure country or the destination country, I do not know.

Comment: I have never had to verify my identity at security _with my passport_ in a European/Schengen airport. At security, identity verification is, in my experience, exclusively done by _boarding pass_, which doesn’t require a passport. Check-in counters are a different matter, of course, and though you don’t mention it, so are the checks at the actual gate (where it’s still common enough to be asked to show both passport and boarding pass).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet ID checks at the gate are mandatory in France I believe. At some point they were dropped but were quickly reintroduced.

Answer (score 6):

I personally had my passport stolen in another Schengen country (Italy), and I need to fly back to another Schengen country (coincidently Germany). I was also unable to get an emergency passport because my home (non-EU country's) embassy did not open before I was scheduled to fly out. I contemplated trying to just board my flight, but ultimately told the airline employees at the check-in counter about my situation and was given a special boarding pass. I did have a printed copy of my passport with me, which made this easier.

Based on my experience, I would recommend arriving early and talking to the airline at the airport, since it's in their best interest to get you home. I would've had to show an ID to board the plane anyways, so without the special boarding pass, I probably couldn't have gotten on.

I have also flown out of Berlin and Munich airport, and never needed to show my passport to board. But I would still recommend talking to the airline at Frankfurt, because their policies could be different there.

Comment: Why it's in the airline's best interest to get you home? If you're denied boarding because of a missing ID, you won't get a refund and there's a chance of you buying another ticket in the future, once your ID problems are fixed. So you end up paying twice for one journey. Isn't that in the airline's interest?

Answer (score 2):

Flying without a passport or an official government-issued ID (the EEA ID card) is a bad idea, because airline employees may want to see it at any time, most likely at boarding. Without one, you'll be denied boarding and of course lose money for your ticket. If you don't want to wait until you get an emergency travel document in Germany, you can do the following:

- Travel overland to Denmark. To be extra safe, I'd recommend crossing the border into Denmark using a local road (on foot, hitchhiking, by a local bus...). The announced temporary border checks are most likely limited to major roads and long-distance trains (I'd be very surprised if the entire Denmark-Germany border was heavily monitored).
- Once you're in Denmark, as a Nordic citizen, if you have any other picture ID (such as a driving license issued in the Nordic countries), your situation is much better. You can also fly from Denmark to Norway using only your driving license as an ID (source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nordic_Passport_Union).
- If you don't have any suitable ID, you can try your luck and continue to Sweden by a ferry from Helsingør to Helsingborg (again, this is mostly used by local traffic and chances of a border check there are lower compared to taking a train from Copenhagen to Malmö). From Helsingborg, you can continue overland (train, bus, hitchhiking) to the Norwegian border.
- Once you get to the Sweden-Norway border, you should be fine. The border is only guarded by Norwegian border guards (not Swedish). As a citizen of Norway, you should be admitted to Norway even without an ID, but you may have to endure lengthy questioning and background checks (in the worst case). Alternately, you can also request an emergency travel document in Denmark or Sweden.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already noted, while there are no systematic border checks within the Schengen area, you are expected to travel with valid proof of identity and might need to show it to the airline or local authorities.

That said, not only passports are acceptable for this purpose: [National IDs work just as well](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/eu-citizen/index_en.htm). (Anecdotally, I've never carried my passport for intra-Schengen travel in the past decade.)

There is an [official list](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/EN/search-by-document-country.html) of acceptable passports and ID cards  by country. Norway seems to be issuing an ID card, so if you happen to have that with you, you should be fine.

Note that driver's licenses, which are often used as de-facto identity cards within many EU countries and also included on the list referenced above, are *not* considered valid identity documents within the Schengen area (even if they're in the [ID-1 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_7810#ID-1) and often "look and feel" just as official as identity cards).

Comment: There *are* systematic checks.  You will not get to the gate without your documents being checked at a german airport.  Those controls are even fully automated at the Munich airport.  Presenting some form of identification is not only expected, it is *mandatory*

Comment: @markgraf True, but it's not a "border check", just an identity check by airline employees. Not the same! And it's true that this is NOT requested at all airports and by all airlines. I flew countless times between Vienna and Zurich and never had to show any ID to anyone, only a boarding pass.

Comment: @Johnnyjanko but markgraf's comment concerns German airports, so it doesn't make any assertions about Zurich or Vienna.

Comment: lxgr: inclusion in PRADO says nothing about a document's suitability for use at an external or internal Schengen border or for any other purpose.  For example (and contrary to the implication in this answer) it includes driver's licenses.  A driver's license is in fact formally accepted as an identity document in many contexts in the Schengen area, but since a driver's license typically says nothing about the bearer's nationality or residence status it is not useful for proving nationality or residence status.  For an internal Schengen flight it may not be necessary to prove these.

Comment: @phoog, true, but other people also mentioned flying out from Munich without having to show an ID. Moreover, what I'm saying is this: even if one has to present an ID when boarding an intra-Schengen flight, that's not a systematic border check.